# I want to insert the listbox items into the database where database value should be integer which is fetched from other table

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms

I'm new to C#. Please help me to build query

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstCountry.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lstCountry.Items[i].Selected == true)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ModuleMaster (ModuleName, Country, ModuleLeader, FirstAml, SecondAml,CoreTeamMember) VALUES (@ModuleName,@Country, @ModuleLeader, @FirstAml, @SecondAml, @CoreTeamMember)"
        + "SELECT * FROM CountryMaster WHERE CountryName IN (" + lstCountry + ");";

        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleName", txtModuleName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country",  lstCountry.Items[i].ToString() );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleLeader", ddModuleLeader.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstAml", ddFirstAML.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondAml", ddSecondAML.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreTeamMember", txtCoreMembers.Text);

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the query I developed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to get helpful answer please add into question helpful info. It is not clear what do you want to do.

Comment: i have a listbox which has countries in it . i have to store the countries but the id of the country should be stored which is present in other table

Comment: have you tried run it?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need something like this

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
     {
        var selected_item = lstCountry.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ModuleMaster (ModuleName, Country, ModuleLeader, FirstAml, SecondAml, CoreTeamMember) "
                       + $"SELECT ModuleName, Country, ModuleLeader, FirstAml, SecondAml, CoreTeamMember FROM CountryMaster WHERE CountryName = {selected_item}";
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
     }
 }
```